# How to copy multiple files from GitHub in a single request

Tags: github, github-api

The [GitHub Webhooks API](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) allows a server to be informed whenever an event occurs on a repo. On push events, the webhook payload (a big, JSON hash) includes an array of modified files.

I need to copy each of the modified files from GitHub to the server, but want to avoid iteratively making HTTP requests. Is there some kind of 'multi-fetch' option?

Notes:

- The server can not use Git or SVN, only the GitHub Web API.
- The array of modified filenames is nested in the payload at `head_commit.modified`.

Comment: If you must use the API, then no -- there's currently no way to fetch the full contents of multiple files with a single request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no API to perform batch requests (which seems to be what you're looking for). Since you can't use Git or SVN, you're limited to requesting each individual file using the Contents API.